Знаки препинания в предложении с вводным словом
Нужно расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении.
Я вам позвоню и возможно приду навестить.

Это хорошо, что автор попытался дать свой вариант ответа (поэтому я и не стала закрывать вопрос). Оформлен он, правда, с ошибкой.
✦ Правильно:
Я вам позвоню и, возможно, приду навестить.
• Объяснения
Я позвоню и приду навестить — однородные сказуемые ("между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами и... запятая не ставится").
Возможно — вводное слово; выделяется с двух сторон запятыми.
Прийти — [я] приду (будущее время).
• Примеры
Вы не будете возражать, если я вам позвоню и, возможно, предложу кое-какую работенку? (Елена Рахманова).
Я просто заплачу за сегодня и, возможно, приду через две недели (Диана Эванс).

Я вам позвоню и, возможно, приду навестить.

Правильно:
Я вам позвоню и, возможно, приду навестить.
Пояснение
Да, действительно, однородные сказуемые здесь есть: позвоню и приду. А вот поговорить — это обстоятельство цели, выраженное инфинитивом.
Это ничего не меняет, небольшая неточность.

Простите,  Sharon, ничего не поняла про "небольшую неточность".

Да пожалуйста, Вот у вас написано: Я позвоню и приду навестить  – однородные сказуемые.  Это так?  "Навестить" входит в состав сказуемого?

Так. Приду навестить = навещу. Навестить, не появившись где-то, не придя куда-либо, невозможно. А Вы хотите сказать, что правильно приду (зачем? для чего?) навестить? А инфинитива "поговорить" тут вообще нет.

Ну да, навестить. Так входит инфинитив в состав сказуемого и какое это сказуемое, если входит?
